# Installing Ubuntu on an eMMC - how can it be so hard?

Tags: 18.04, acer, emmc

I have an Acer Revo M1-601 (https://www.acer.com/ac/en/CA/content/model/DT.B28AA.001) mini-PC with 32GB eMMC built-in storage. I've spent the whole weekend trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on it  but I just can't get it to work. I run the installation from a USB drive and it finishes without any issues but when I restart the computer it can't find any bootable media. I have read previous posts on this issue here on this web site (this being one example [eMMC Boot - Installation & Compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879986/emmc-boot-installation-compatibility)) and done a lot of Googling but nothing seems to work for me.

I have tested a lot of different BIOS settings. It's now set to UEFI with secure boot off.

I can't figure out how this can be so difficult. It never had any problems booting in Windows 10. I'm not completely new to Ubuntu. I've installed it on many machines before without any issues but I'm ready to give up on this one. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Please create a question we can answer "how can it be so hard?" is impossible to answer. "I can't figure out how this can be so difficult." is a private matter between you and your system ;-)  "I restart the computer it can't find any bootable media" is difficult to answer.  But let's start at the beginning. how did you set up UEFI? Did you add an UEFI partition on the emmc for Ubuntu? If not it will never boot. And since someone probably pre-installed one for w10 that will likely then work with no issues (please add extra info into the question and I will remove comments as we progress)

Comment: Maybe you need to add the efi file yourself ? This can be done from the BIOS.

Comment: I had a similar issue recently when installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 on an older machine.  The installer booted fine and the installation completed, but then I got "No bootable media".  It was some issue with the way in which the "Live" installation media, the default choice on the Ubuntu site, installed the bootloader.  Using the "alternate" full fat installation media worked fine for me however.  You can download it here:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/

Comment: @Rinzwind - Sorry for not hiding my frustration better :) To answer your question, I didn't do anything in particular in the installation to set it up for UEFI. I changed my firmware (BIOS) settings as explained above and than ran a default installation with the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option which is how I've always done it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth a colleague of mine helped me fix this. His solution was to put the boot loader on a USB-stick and the actual operating system on the eMMC. Not a very elegant solution but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Used Gparted Live iso on SD card to remove all chrome partitions from Emmc, created one ext4 partition.

Now the Ubuntu install SD card runs fine, and the Toshiba can be used for years to come instead of being e-waste.