# Kubuntu on eMMC

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, emmc

I'm installing Kubuntu onto a laptotp (Acer Aspire ES13) which has an eMMC as storage. Googling, I found out that Linux usually has problems installing on an eMMC... is that true? Will my laptop work? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I guess it is hard as installing a normal SSD or USB stick. Be aware of the BIOS hidden command `ctrl+S` on Acer laptops. https://askubuntu.com/questions/879986/emmc-boot-installation-compatibility?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Ok! Thank you! :)